# How do I fix the following margin in an HTML while using bootstrap css?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

The following HTML uses some given style sheets which I like, but in this case the text is pushed too much to the left when I use the class "container". I would just want to change the class "container" so that the text is not pushed so much, while retaining the HTML the same pretty much (including the CSS pointers). Is that possible?

```
<html>

<head>
```

I tried the solution below:

```
<html>

<head>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery.urlshortener.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">


</head>

<body>

<style>
.padding0
{
  padding: 0px !important;
}
</style>

<div class="container padding0">
This appears too much to the right.
</div>
</body>
</html>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery.urlshortener.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">


</head>

<body>

<div class="container">
This appears too much to the right.
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

still not aligned to the left (on Firefox).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your container class have padding-left and padding-right 15 px.
You can add a class padding0 to avoid the paddings on this.

```css
.padding0
{
  padding: 0px !important;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery.urlshortener.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">


</head>

<body>

<div class="container padding0"> 
This appears too much to the right. Not anymore :)
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks! it moved by just a little bit, it is still quite in the center. is there a way to make the margin disappear altogether?

Comment: @kloop is your code different than the whats we have in the above snippet, here its left aligned now.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap is responsive. As such based on various screen widths, it has width properties assigned to the container class. 
For width below 970px, it is 750px, above it has 970px.
and since margin is auto for container it will make it center aligned.

If you are not using responsive design, then make following class:

```
.container{margin: 0 0; padding: 0 0;}
```

but it is advised not to do that, so you can create the following:

```
<style>.marPad0{margin: 0 0; padding: 0 0;</style>
<div class="container marPad0">
    This appears too much to the right.
</div>
```

This will solve your issue.